# Dataloader() takes no arguments Error while executing a code to run a file in python using OOPS methodology

Tags: python, oop, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

[image]
[image]

Hi Guys,
I am trying to create a training, validation and test dataset in python for bike sharing dataset using Object oriented programming.

I have first created a method called "DATALOADER" to read the file and then split the data into train, validation and test set. However, I am facing some challenges while executing the code.

Pasting the code above  and error response below. Need some help with that.

**Error Message:**
****---------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)**
**<ipython-input-29-29ec681918b0> in <module>**
**----> 1 dataloader = Dataloader('C:/Users/pbhal/Downloads/hour.csv/hour.csv')**
**2 train, val, test = dataloader.getData()**
**3 fullData = dataloader.getFullData()**
**4**
**5 category_features = ['season', 'holiday', 'mnth', 'hr', 'weekday', 'workingday', 'weathersit']**

**TypeError: Dataloader() takes no arguments****

I was trying to create a train, validation and test set out of hour.csv datafile. However , it did not work out

Comment: Please dont post code as images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo, you should use `__init__` (two underscores) instead of `_init_`. This means that your class does not have an initialization method defined, and the fallback (the Python class `object` I think) does not receive any argument.

You can validate that this is the issue with a small empty class:

```
class Example:
    pass

a = Example()  # Works
b = Example(1)  # Fails with "TypeError: Example() takes no arguments"
```